# Proof: Every $\mu$-measurable set is a $\mu \lfloor B$-measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

Theorem:

> Let $X$ be a set, $\mu: P(X) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a measure and
>   $A_{\mu}$ the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu$-measurable sets of $X$, $B
> > \subset X$ arbitrary.
>
> Show that for the restriction of $\mu$ to $B$, $\mu\lfloor B$,
>   $A_{\mu}$ is a subset of the $\sigma$-algebra of
>   $\mu\lfloor$-measurable sets.

I now that a measurable set $A$ is defined as: $A$ such that $\forall C \subset X$: $\mu(C) = \mu(A \cap C) + \mu(A \setminus X)$. And I have to show that for every such $A \in A_{\mu}$ it holds: $\forall Z \subset B: \; \mu(B \cap Z) = \mu(B \cap A \cap Z) + \mu(B \cap A \setminus Z)$.

How do I go upon proving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $C=B \cap Z$. You get $\mu(B\cap A \cap Z)+\mu (B\cap A \setminus Z)\leq \mu(B\cap A \cap Z)+\mu(A\setminus C)=\mu (A \cap C)+\mu(A\setminus C)$ [where we used the fact that $B\cap A \setminus Z \subseteq A\setminus C$]. Now the measurability of $A$ gives $\mu(B\cap A \cap Z)+\mu (B\cap A \setminus Z)\leq \mu(C)=\mu (B \cap Z)$.  The reverse inequality is always true.